# Powershell use return value on a different function

Tags: powershell

```
function printHelloWorld{
param(
    [String]$var

)
$returnVal = ""
$returnVal = helper($var)
Write-Host "$returnVal"
}

function helper{

param(
    [String]$var
)

$returnVal = $var + " World"

return $returnVal | out-null
}
```

When I run printHelloWorld -var "Hello" I want "Hello World" in the output.
How can use $returnVal from helper function in function printHelloWorld?

Answer (score 0):

Drop the | out-null in helper and the parentheses in the call to helper.